# React state update while rendering

Tags: reactjs

I need to update a state in my react app while rendering the content. Is there any option to update state while rendering.

Note: I am very new to react

Comment: actually its only re-render when you update state

Comment: you can use either componentDidMount() or componentDidUpdate()                           Note: componentDidMount()  calls only once when page/component is mounted /rendered   and componentDidUpdate()     is calls each time when your state has changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentDidUpdate()` Lifecycle method.

and inside `componentDidUpdate()` function update your state.

FYI: `componentDidUpdate()` calls every time if component gets updtated.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

Futureproofing Note: answer relevant to v16.4.

The answer to your question depends on what you mean by saying "while rendering".

When react invokes the render method of a component, it does not really render anything, yet. The results of the render method will undergo "reconciliation", which means that it will be compared to what's rendered at the moment. If a difference is detected, react will actually re-render the DOM, as effectively as it can.

This means that you can not do anything when react is actually rendering / re-rendering the DOM, since your code is not being executed.

You can, however, do something after the render method has been invoked.
As others have stated before me, the *componentDidUpdate* method is the place.

Note that the fact that this method has been invoked does not necessarily mean react has re-rendered the DOM. It only assures that the component is in sync with the DOM.

Do note that since setting state CAN cause a re-render, so you should really be careful about setting state in componentDidUpdate - or you might cause an infinite loop of sorts.

Even if you correctly implement shouldComponentUpdate, stopping the render cycle from ever reaching cDU- react docs suggest the result of sCU can be taken as a hint in the future, which will break your app in future releases.

So, if you must setState in cDU - you must check that this setState is required, and is not a side-effect of setting the state in the first place.